# "Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'" - Why is my useRef undefined?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have the following code in my react component:

```tsx
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(5);
const unMount = useRef();
unMount.current = () => {    // <- gives error "Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'"
  console.log(`The counter is: ${counter}`);
};

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if (unMount.current)
      unMount.current();
  };
}, [])
```

I need to access the *counter* variable in the cleanup function of my useEffect hook. And the cleanup needs to run on component unmount only. Also, the *counter* may change between the first and last render of the component. I have found [the following guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139924/how-to-use-the-useeffect-hook-on-component-unmount-to-conditionally-run-code) for achieving my goals, but when I try to assign a function to the useRef's current object, I get the error `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'`.

I'm new to React and think I'm missing something with my hook declaration, but I'm not sure what. There are [some similar cases on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368407/type-void-is-not-assignable-to-type), but they don't have the same error message and they don't deal with hooks. Why am I getting the `Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'undefined'` error?

Comment: The return type of a `useRef` call is inferred from what you pass into it (unless e.g. you use TypeScript and explicitly declare the type parameter like `useRef<YourType>()`). Since you just call `useRef()`, you didn't pass anything into it,  it's kind of like `useRef(undefined)` and the return type is inferred as `React.MutableRefObject<undefined>`. So the `current` property is typed as `undefined`

Comment: Can you use `let unMount = useRef(() => { console.log(counter);});`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using typescript declare a type along with the useRef hook

```
const unMount = useRef<()=>void>();
```